# unable to delete or move first step from logic app?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created a logic app and want to change a flow of logic app but it seems i need to re-create all logic app from scratch.

Is there any way to delete first step or move it in logic app?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need this first step and you can't delete or move it, but you can edit in code and replace it with another trigger action.